# What's the best way to retrieve the value in a nullable Optional?

Tags: java, scala, java-8, functional-programming, option-type

Suppose you have an `Optional<T>` variable that could take on one of 3 values:

- the value T
- an Optional with a null T in it
- the variable is null itself

What's the best way to retrieve the value `T` or `null` otherwise?

Here's one method:

```
Optional<String> op = ...
String str = op != null ? op.orElse(null) : null;
```

Here's another method:

```
String str = Optional.ofNullable(op).flatMap(innerOpt -> innerOpt).orElse(null);
```

What are the pros and cons of each? Is one more performant? Is one more scala-esque? Is one more readable/maintainable?

Comment: An Optional should never, ever, ever be null. If it's the case, don't work around it: fix the code.

Comment: Indeed. One possible fix is to use an `Optional<Optional<T>>` ;) Although I would seriously doubt your **model** if you require it in the first place.

Comment: Why is this tagged "scala"? It's pretty clearly a java question.

Comment: `Optional<Optional<T>>` -> *my brain explodes*  OK seriously, I don't like `Optional`.  You should use `Optional` if it's a required part of the API.  Otherwise, don't.  My 2 bits.  (OK, yes I missed the winky smile on first read.)

Comment: `Optional<Optional<T>>` is quite pathological, but can be easily reduced with `flatMap`

Comment: "an Optional with a null T in it" — impossible. You can't store null in Java's Optional.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon that is the definition of empty in Java, an Optional with a null value; there is no None.

Comment: @som-snytt The definition of an Optional is "A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value" (from [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)). An empty Optional might be implemented by storing null, but that's an implementation detail. The JavaDoc consistently uses phrases like "if a value is present" and "empty Optional". We should avoid ambiguous language like "null value", which sounds like it refers to `Optional.of(null)` (which throws an NPE).

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Yes, you're right. Maybe the word "store" made me think implementation, and I'm still more comfortable with semantics of `scala.Option`.

Answer (score 5):

The first one can be simplified as just:

```
String str = op.orElse(null);
```

And that would be the most readable of possibilities you've written.

It's commonly said, that `Optional` is not for `null` handling, but it's just a matter of taste in my opinion. Suppose you have to chain, like in kotlin:

```
object?.child?.grandChild
```

At each level we're performing a null check. In java it would be:

```
object == null ? null : (object.child == null ? null : object.child.grandChild)
```

Which is a bit eye-hurting. It'd write:

```
Optional.ofNullable(object)
    .map(Parent::getChild)
    .map(Child::getGrandChild)
    .orElse(null);
```

Might be a bit more verbose, but for me - quite readable. As I said - it's a matter of taste.

P.S.: `Optional` is a way to ease handling `null` by wrapping it in monad. Do not let an `Optional` be `null`!

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica so you would go with the first option?

Comment: Well, yes, but again, the author of the question should try and fix his code. If something is `null` it doesn't mean that you should assign another variable to `null`. Generally I would expect a guard statement and a runtime exception. Anytime anybody assigns `null` to something they are falling in a trap.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica ok, so this boil down to not using `null` as special value. But not always is it possible (for example integrating with external database). If I do have a chain of possible `null`s, I'd seriously consider using `Optional`. Sorry to hear I might not understand readability:)

Comment: Whoops, sorry confused question and answer author because of the type of question you asked :) Fixed comment.

Comment: I agree that the Optional should never be null, but I'm working with existing code base and trying to patch up the piece of code that I do own

Comment: Totally readable. Can't agree with "guard and throw", but worth saying that the OP left out "throw null" as an option.

Comment: I also disagree with exception driven design. Despite readability and maintainability it's just a runtime bloat.

Comment: @kane there’s no programming without communication (between the developers). If you’re not responsible for the mess, talk to the one who is. Don’t pile workaround atop workaround because nobody feels responsible.

Answer (score 1):

Justifying the Scala tag:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.3).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val x: java.util.Optional[String] = null
x: java.util.Optional[String] = null

scala> import scala.jdk.OptionConverters._
import scala.jdk.OptionConverters._

scala> Option(x).map(_.toScala).flatten.getOrElse("default")
res0: String = default
```